# Ubuntu unity instead of xfce

Tags: unity, 18.04, xfce, vnc

I launched the free instance in aws with ubuntu 18.04. I followed this guide to connect with putty: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

It works. I also followed this guide to connect with a remote desktop connection from windows and realvnc from my mobile: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-ubuntu-1604-windows/

It works. The problem is that I prefer the default desktop environment of Ubuntu and I want either to revert back to it or to add some functionality where I can switch from one to the other. I am a noob in Linux

Thanks in advance!
George.

Comment: 18.04 uses Gnome3 as default desktop environment, not unity.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. I run 16.04. How do I run it? I will put it in /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh